# Lenovo ThinkCentre M78, Processor Type

Tags: lenovo, amd-processor, hardware-certification

I see that Lenovo ThinkCentre M78 is certified by Ubuntu, http://www.ubuntu.com/certification/hardware/201212-12227.  The processor they tested in certifying was an AMD A6-5400B.  However, I would like to get an AMD A8-6500B processor.  Should I be confident that Ubuntu would be similarly as stable with the AMD A8-6500B as the certified processor?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Those APUs are not even from the same family. The A6-5400B is a Trinity family processor, and the A8-6500B is a Richland one. It is very likely that they need different drivers.

Comment: As a follow-up, I have had the Lenovo desktop I mention for the last year running Xubuntu 14.04, and it works great even though it is not one of the certified machines. Thank you for the insight in your answer.